# Magento 2 - Observer on event 'sales_order_place_after' not working

Tags: events, magento2, observers

I am working on a magento 2 observer (without success), to execute a cURL request to a system with the orderid after a order is placed.

Currently I just send an email, but that's for testing purpose only

Working on a Plesk server with a fresh Magento 2.3.2 install (no sample data) and added 1 product. So, fresh webshop with 1 product in total.

Currently I have the following code:

/app/code/CompanyName/ModuleName/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="companyname__modulename_observer_afterplaceorder" instance="CompanyName\ModuleName\AfterPlaceOrder"  />
    </event>

<config>
```

/app/code/CompanyName/ModuleName/AfterPlaceOrder.php

```
<?php
namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class AfterPlaceOrder implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        Mage::log("Start execute module");


        $headers   = array();
        $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
        $headers[] = "Content-type: text/html";
        $headers[] = "From: Test SYSTEM";
        $headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
        mail('testemail@companyname.com', 'Test message', "Order placed", implode("\r\n", $headers));

        Mage::log("End of email");
    }


}
```

I've also tried other events like:
 - checkout_onepage_controller_success_action
 - sales_order_place_after
 - sales_order_place_before
 - sales_order_save_after

Logs don't seem to work, mail doesn't send and tried die() but nothing works.

It's probably that the event is never fired, but I just can't figure out why.

Can you guys see the error?

P.S. What do you use to debug? Is there a better way then logging?
P.S. I'd also like to now if a observer is the best way for this. Any suggestions?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your /app/code/CompanyName/ModuleName/etc/events.xml is missing the observer folder also the close of the config tag. You could use the event:

checkout_onepage_controller_success_action

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="companyname__modulename_observer_afterplaceorder" instance="CompanyName\ModuleName\Observer\AfterPlaceOrder"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

To get the orderid just use:
$orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();